# Boundary distance search for points

Tags: qgis, distance

I have loaded a map layer (containing school catchment boundaries) and I have also plotted numerous houses (as points within a layer). How can I search for houses which are within 2km of each boundary?

[image: here is map I currently have]

I am using QGIS and am a relatively new user so don't know much about the programme.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: I am using QGIS and am a relatively new user so don't know much about the programme. Sorry for any inconvenience caused

Answer (score 2):

You can create 2 km **buffer** from your polygons and then use **select by location** tool to find interesting points

Comment: You're' welcome, you can mark my answer as best answer ;)